# Spreadsheet Script Access

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to prohibit users of shared spreadsheets view/edit access to the included scripts while still allowing them to use the script as a function or macro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this excerpt from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scripts_google_accounts) answers your question -

> For container-bound scripts, the access rules for the scripts are a
>   little bit different. A script project that is bound to a container,
>   such as a Google Spreadsheet or Google Site, will inherit the
>   permissions of the container. For example, if user1@example.com has
>   edit access to a Google Spreadsheet, then user1@example.com will also
>   be able to view and edit any scripts that are bound to that
>   spreadsheet.
>
> Note: For container-bound scripts created prior to June 8, 2012, the
>   Share button will remain and any project-specific sharing settings
>   will be preserved if the checkbox to "Allow document collaborators to
>   edit project" or "Allow site collaborators and owners to edit project"
>   was not selected for that script. In this case, if you click the Share
>   button, you'll see an option to upgrade to the simplified sharing
>   model described above for those projects.

Answer (score -1):

Not directly, but you could simply code calls to proprietary or 'secret sauce' as a library. this wouldn't prevent a Spreadsheet user being able to edit the code that called the Library code, but it will conceal the primary functions.

It depends on your motivations for concealing the script code as to hw effective this would be.

Comment: That is currently how I am doing it but I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution. As you pointed out the calls to the library code can be edited.

Comment: add a request to the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=spreadsheets&sort=-modified&colspec=ID+Status+Summary+Type+Opened+Stars+Component+Closed+Modified&cells=tiles) for private functions. I couldn't find an existing one to upvote. This is a request I have heard before.